# ZooKeeper Service in E-MapReduce Cluster

Tags: alibaba-cloud-ecs

ZooKeeper Service is by default enabled in E-MapReduce in Alibaba Cloud ECS. I can only have access to 3 nodes in the cluser. It is not allowing to access more than 3 nodes no matter how many machines are currently in the cluster.

How can I access more than 3 nodes. Is there any limitation for the same.

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The document states as you indicated.
"
ZooKeeper will have only 3 nodes no matter how many machines are currently in the cluster. More nodes are not supported currently.
"
1, It would be great to know why you need more than 3 zookeeper instances?
2, In case of so many scenarios in 1 cluster, would it make sense to split them into different clusters?